# Tabs Won't Work Looping through PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I'm trying to write simple tags that I can use to loop through PHP, but it's not working. I'm not certain why. You can check it out here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LbEJqx

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('ul.tabs li').click(function() {
var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

$('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
$('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

$(this).addClass('current');
$("#" + tab_id).addClass('current');
})
})
```

When I loop it through php, it breaks. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: You're not including jQuery in your script. If you include jQuery it works fine.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jVEeaE

Answer (score 0):

I added jQuery to your CodePen and it worked fine.  Add jQuery to the head of your page:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I looped it through core php, and it's not working. Without the php it works fine, but when I add the php, it won't work.

Comment: Can you provide more detail about what "not working" means?  Post source code of your PHP script, along with any relevant error messages.